# Нужна ли запятая перед словом "соответственно"?

Tags: пунктуация

Скачок роста цен на канцтовары за 10 месяцев текущего года был значительно ниже общего уровня инфляции и составил 7,2% и 5,3% соответственно.

Comment: Ну почему же ниже? Наверное, выше...  Ведь 7,2% > 5,3%.

Comment: Более-менее читаемым был бы примерно такой вариант: _Скачок роста цен на канцтовары за 10 месяцев текущего года был значительно <...> общего уровня инфляции (7,2% и 5,3% соответственно)._

Answer (score 3):

При попытке понять смысл исходной фразы сразу возникает вопрос: где те **два вида канцтоваров**, которым "соответствуют" два числа? Будь они на месте, можно было бы обосновать ненужность запятой, заменить "скачок роста" на "рост" или "скачок" и на этом закончить. Если же желаемый смысл заключается в сопоставлении цен и уровня инфляции, то нужно убрать "соответствие", поскольку сопоставляемые сущности находятся в разных частях предложения и в разных падежах, причем цифры упомянуты в последовательности, противоположной имеющемуся "ниже":

> Рост цен на канцтовары за 10 месяцев текущего года был значительно
> ниже общего уровня инфляции (7,2%) и составил 5,3%.

Comment: О! Еще одно прочтение. Вполне, кстати разумное. Но отнюдь не очевидное, тем более - не единственное. см. ответы slava1947 и behemothus

Comment: *поскольку сопоставляемые сущности находятся в разных частях предложения и в разных падежах* - да кабы только это... Они изначально несопоставимы. Скачок роста - это именно что **изменение** роста, от периода к периоду, например. Вторая производная, грубо говоря. А инфляция - это вообще из другой оперы, и если и производная, то никак не вторая. Это математически. А экономически инфляция и рост цен связаны, но никак не таким примитивным образом, что их можно "связывать" по соответствию.  Это, конечно, выходит за рамки стилистики и лингвистики вообще, но таки факт.

Comment: Думаю, что сопоставление разных сущностей с одинаковой размерностью величин (проценты) в другом контексте _допустимо_: "рост цен на эти товары и общая инфляция за период составляют 5% и 7% _соответственно_.  "Скачок роста" в этом предложении я воспринял как недоразумение и заменил на "рост" (изменение за период времени), поскольку под "скачком" обычно понимают _мгновенное_ изменение (напр. с утра 1-го числа; ну можно еще как-то понять "скачок цен" - с момента, когда ими в последний раз интересовались).

Answer (score 2):

> Скачок роста цен на канцтовары за 10 месяцев текущего года был
> значительно ниже общего уровня инфляции и составил 7,2% и 5,3%
> соответственно.

?

Более-менее читаемым был бы примерно такой вариант:

> Скачок роста цен на канцтовары за 10 месяцев текущего года был
> значительно <...> общего уровня инфляции (7,2% и 5,3% соответственно).

Обратите внимание на некоторую путаницу в цифрах: если "скачок роста цен на канцтовары" действительно составил 7,2%, а "уровень инфляции" — 5,3%, то вместо "ниже" в предложении надо было бы написать "выше".

Comment: Согласен, что в исходном виде тут невообразимая путаница с понятиями.  Я плюсанул от чистого сердца, хотя вы не рассмотрели иную возможность понимания... Наподобие той, что у меня в ответе. Или вы такое исключаете априори?

Comment: @behemothus Честно говоря, такая версия и не приходила мне в голову. Да, думаю, и Максим не это имел в виду. Но вот с Вашим замечанием, что разбираемая "фраза настолько плохо сформулирована, что невозможно понять смысл" — полностью согласен.

Comment: Понимаете, мне "в прошлой жизни" довелось много читать диссертаций  и вообще научных работ,  написанных технарями не просто "от сохи", а от "мотыги", русский у них был "со словарем"... Такого начитаешься... Приходилось по контектсту видеть тот смысл, которой другому бы в голову не пришел. Обжегшись на том молоке, теперь на воду дую.

Comment: А здесь как раз тот случай, когда "нормальное" понимание сталкивается с проблемами при осмыслении сути сказанного. Выше - ниже - это еще цветочки. Ягодки - в том, что величины эти в экономическом понимании принципиально не сравниваемые. Ну примерно как скорость света и масса Солнца.

Answer (score 1):

Считаю, что на вопрос невозможно ответить адекватно.
Фраза настолько плохо сформулирована, что невозможно понять смысл, конкретно - роль или функцию этого "соответственно".

Вам надо уточнить, что именно чему тут соответствует - или же смысл "соответствия" просто в том, что из одного показателя (какого, кстати?) вытекает или следует другой.

И дело даже не в том, что здесь есть и математическая, и экономическая нечеткость.  (Математическая: cкачок цен - это как и почему он в процентах? А экономическая - почему сравниваются две такие несопоставимые вещи?). Тут чисто семантическая неувязка, которая не позволяет ответить на вопрос.

Что такое "соответственно" в роли члена предложения? Дается один (реже два) показателя - и две величины/характеристики, первая ***соответствует*** первому показателю, вторая - второму.

Пример.
***Глаголы совершенного и несовершенного вида отвечают на вопросы "что сделал" и "что делал"  соответственно***

***В прошлом месяце в Урюпинске зафиксировано больше случаев разгильдяйства, чем в  Мусохранове - 5 и 3 случая соответственно*** - slava1947 примерно так и понял вашу фразу, но для меня это совсем не очевидно.

В таких случаях запятая не нужна, это понятно.

Случай же использования "соответственно" как вводного предполагает, что во фразе на самом деле не устанавливаются соответствия.

Я не буду тут тут изобретать примеры, просто чуть переделаю вашу фразу ради доведения её до возможно прочтения.

***Скачок роста цен на канцтовары за 10 месяцев текущего года составил 7,2% (в начале периода) против 5,3% (в конце) и, соответственно, был значительно ниже общего уровня инфляции.***

Чем не вариант-то? Подозреваю, что вы не это имели в виду... Но кто знает-то?

(+)
*После замечания в комментариях вынужден добавить, что не рассматриваю последний свой текст (со "скачком роста" цен) как рекомендуемую правку. Приношу извинения тем, кто понял иначе. На самом деле это лишь пример того, как можно использовать "соответственно" в роли водного слова, а заодно и того, как можно понять (вероятно - превратно) исходное плохо сформулированное предложение.
В той фразе "скачок" означает изменение показателя "рост цен" с одного значения (с 7,2% до 5,3% - или наоборот, это совершенно не важно). Фразу я чуть изменил, дабы попонятнее стало, о чем я говорю. Но от сути не отказываюсь.*

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, ОБЩИЙ уровень инфляции - это правильно?  Ведь слово "общий" уже есть в определении инфляции. Инфля́ция (лат. inflatio «вздутие») — повышение ОБЩЕГО уровня цен на товары и услуги на длительный срок. Я была уверена, что это тоже стилистическая ошибка, но никто не стал ее исправлять.

Comment: *ОБЩИЙ уровень инфляции - это правильно?*  - хороший вопрос... Но вообще-то это к Росстату, который без пояснений свободно оперирует именно таким термином. Видимо, дело в том, что вы привели здесь бытовое понимание инфляции, в а экономике используют несколько другое, причем в нескольких на первый взгляд совершенно  разных формулировках, хотя на саом деле они эквивалентны. Мне ближе, например, такая. **Инфляция — это переполнение каналов денежного обращения избыточной денежной массой, проявляемое в росте товарных цен.**

Comment: Это, правда, не до конца снимает вопрос том, что такое общая инфляция - и чем она отличается от "необщей". Но по крайней мере слова "общий" в этой формулировке нет. А ближе мне подобная формулировка тем, что рост цен здесь - следствие инфляции, а не её определение. Любой серьезный экономист подтвердит, что так оно и есть. Рост цен - всего лишь проявление инфляции, а сама инфляция - это увеличение денежной массы , как правило не обеспеченное товарным предложениям. Тогда и слово "ОБЩАЯ" при термине "инфляция" становится более или менее понятным.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В приведённом предложении - нет, хотя *соответственно* может быть и вводным.

Смотрим разъяснения Справки Грамоты.ру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вариант редактирования:

***Рост цен** на канцтовары за 10 месяцев текущего года был значительно выше **уровня** инфляции – **7,2% и 5,3% соответственно**.*

Запятая не нужна, в данном случае «соответственно» – это **наречие, а не вводное слово.**  Оно имеет прямое значение соответствия  названных цифр  указанным ранее статьям.

В предложении исправлены **стилистические неточности.**

Инфля́ция (лат. inflatio «вздутие») — повышение **общего** уровня цен на товары и услуги на длительный срок.

**Фраза стандартная:** в основной части указываются темы, а затем в **ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНОЙ** конструкции даются их цифровые показатели.

В этом случае **не требуется грамматическая согласованность** между двумя частями предложения.

Comment: _Sharon: 
Скачок роста цен на канцтовары за 10 месяцев текущего года был значительно выше общего уровня инфляции и составил 7,2% и 5,3% соответственно.

Сравнивается рост цен и уровень инфляции, выраженные в процентах.

Запись вполне кооректная (с учетом иправления). <...> Пример:

Кусок металла массой 780 г в воде весит 6,8 Н, а в двух других жидкостях 7 и 7,1 Н соответственно._=== Sharon, Вы действительно не видите разницы между рассматриваемым примером и примером с куском металла?

Comment: 1) Я вижу СТИЛИСТИЧЕСКИЕ неточности фразы, которые должны исправляться при ответе – желательно спокойно, доброжелательно, без лишних эмоций и ненужной иронии, которая просто зашкаливает. 2) СОДЕРЖАНИЕ фразы, как мне кажется, такое: есть уровень инфляции (5,3%) и есть рост цен в отдельной отрасли (7,2%). Но у вас, возможно, другое мнение?  3) Вопрос же был о постановке запятой, поэтому после исправления стилистических ошибок отвечать надо на этот вопрос, он должен быть в центре внимания. Не стоит забывать, что у нас форум русского языка, а не экономический форум.

Comment: **Sharon, ну что Вы постоянно крутитесь, как уж на сковородке!**  Сейчас  пишите: _1) Я вижу СТИЛИСТИЧЕСКИЕ неточности фразы, которые должны исправляться при ответе…_  Да конечно должны!!! Но Вы же НЕ ЗАМЕТИЛИ их в своём первом варианте ответа! Написали в нём чушь, снабдив её комментарием: _Запись вполне корректная_. Исправили свой ответ только сейчас — спустя 12 часов после того, как мне пришлось Вас практически ткнуть в просмотр Вашего варианта предложения, которое Вы первоначально сочли "вполне корректным". И ещё после этого пытаетесь меня поучать… Ну просто нет слов!

Comment: @Sharon, я не собираюсь обсуждать риторику вашу и вашего оппонента, это ваши тараканы, но вы за разговорами о том, как надо (или не надо) разговаривать, прячете суть замечаний. А они очень весомы. slava1947, если я его понял правильно, совершенно логично говорит о том, что за путанностью исходной фразы разговоры о правильности пунктуации умозрительны. Я эту позицию более чем разделяю. Поэтому фразу надо сначала исправить, убедиться, что исправление правильно передает мысль автора - и только потом начинать обсуждать пунктуацию уже в новой, исправленной фразе.

Comment: Вы же пытаетесь сделать все наоборот. Сначала расставить знаки - потом задуматься о смысле.  И дело не в экономической сути, бог с ней, хотя ляп очевидный...  Тут именно синтаксис туманен...

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, а минусовать ответ-то зачем? Я полагаю неверным употребление сочетания "скачок роста цен"  (вероятно,  имелся в виду просто рост цен), но вы его сочли корректным.

Comment: @Sharon ваш ответ мне не нравился изначально. Но в нынешнем виде, после всех ваших правок, он уже перестал быть ответом на вопрос.

Comment: Почему перестал-то? Про необособление "соответственно" написано, вариант правки приведен, стилистические ошибки указаны.

Comment: Потому, наверное, что за деревьями леса не видно. Вы все усилия свели к доказательству того, что slava1947 неправ.

Comment: *Я полагаю неверным употребление сочетания "скачок роста цен"* - да, здесь выглядит странным, в хотя принципе и такое возможно, но я это не обсуждал. *(вероятно, имелся в виду просто рост цен), но вы его сочли корректным* - не помню, чтобы я говорил что-то по поводу корректности этой конструкции.

Comment: В вашем ответе приведен вариант правки, где вы используете "скачок роста цен".

Comment: *В вашем ответе приведен вариант правки, где вы используете "скачок роста цен"* -  Ну так это же вариант того, как МОЖНО понять эту фразу. Именно о том и шла речь. О том, что неверные формулировки приводят к неверному, даже абсурдному пониманию. А в принципе в понятии "скачок роста" - не вижу ничего страшного, если им правильно пользоваться. Не хочу здесь математику объяснять, но это в пределе - как **вторая** производная. А просто рост - первая.производная.

Comment: А мне показалось, что это тот окончательный текст, котоый вы предлагаете использовать. Я думаю, что это именно  "скачок" виноват во всей этой путанице, его надо было сразу убрать. Иначе получаются три статьи (начало периода, конец периода и инфляция), а цифры только две.

Comment: _Sharon: И ошибки вот: сейчас "пишИте"._ === Согласен, и у меня ошибки могут проскочить. Написал бы "пишИте" в ответе — давно бы исправил. Но, к сожалению, при написании комментариев не всегда удаётся их сразу перечитать, а по истечении 5 минут — поезд уже ушёл... А удалять тот свой комментарий (с "пишИте") не хочу: пусть остаётся.

Comment: Я делаю так. Копирую текст, вставляю в новый комментарий, а старый удаляю. И 5 минут в моем распоряжении для исправления. Кстати, если уж у нас разговор зашел, то как вы относитесь к "скачку роста цен", который прсутствует в вашем ответе. Не хотите его убрать? По-моему, это стилистическая ошибка, плеоназм вроде бы. Должно быть что-то одно - рост цен или скачок цен. Как вы думаете?